# How to add overflow ellipsis to an element using CSS and React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have to apply overflow ellipsis to only one type of item when the content in span exceeds overflows.

What I am trying to do?
I have a list of notifications for items. For one type of notification "message" I need to add overflow ellipsis to it. I have tried something like below, but doesn't work.

```
class main extends React.Purecomponent {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.comment_ref = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.notification.type === 'comment') {
        this.set_overflow_class();
    }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.notification.id !== this.props.notification.id && 
        this.props.notification.type === 'comment') {
        this.set_overflow_class();
    }
}

set_overflow_class = () => {
    const element = this.comment_ref.current;
    console.log("comment ref", element);
    if(element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth) {
        element.classList.add('overflowing');
    }
};

switch(notification.type) {
case 'uploaded':
    return (
        <ListItem icon={<Svg/>} text={name + 
        'created item' + item.name} timestamp={timestamp}>
            <div className="image">
                <Image
                    width={70}
                    height={70}
                    item_id={item.id}
                />
            </div>
        </ListItem>
    );
case 'comment':
    return (
        <ListItem icon={<Svg/>} text={name + 
           'commented item' + item.name} ref={this.comment_ref} 
            className="span" timestamp= {timestamp}>
        </ListItem>
    );

function ListItem(props) {
    return (
        <li className="item">
            <div className="details">
                {props.icon}
                <span ref={props.ref} className={props.className}>{props.text} 
                </span>
            </div>
            {props.children}
            <Timestamp>{props.timestamp}</Timestamp>
        </li>
    );
}
```

but it throws an error that says: `cannot set scrollwidth of undefined`. It seems it is not able to identify the span element.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to this by adding text-overflow: ellipsis css rule.

Like below,

```
case 'comment':
    return (
        <ListItem icon={<Svg/>} text={name + 
            'commented item' + item.name} 
             className="additional_details" timestamp= {timestamp}>
        </ListItem>
   );
```

function ListItem(props) {
       return (
           
               
                   {props.icon}
                   {props.text} 
                   
               
               {props.children}
               {props.timestamp}
            
       );
    }

```
.additional_details {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 20px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```